# 3D image to sequence of images

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using a pre-trained Keras VGG-16 model on 3D images. Since VGG-16 only takes `LxLx3` images, I want to provide a sequence of `LxLx3` images for each 3D image with stride of 1 as the input. Is there a quick way in Keras to do this apart from processing all the input before?

Example: I have:

```
[2d_img1,2d_img2,.....2d_imgn]
```

I want the input as:

```
[[2d_img1,2d_img2,2d_img3], [2d_img2,2d_img3,2d_img4].....]
```

Comment: Maybe write a custom layer? But I would go with preprocessing or write a data generator if the dataset size is too big to preprocess all the images at once.